# Why does this REN command return "The syntax of the command is incorrect"?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, rename

I have some files in a folder like:

> 1. Happysong.m4a.mp3
> 2. Sad song ft. H.E.R.m4a.mp3

I want to rename these to:

> 1. Happysong.mp3
> 2. Sad song ft. H.E.R.mp3

Here is my code for `test.bat` file which is placed in the same folder:

```sh
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir  /b /a-d *.m4a.mp3') do (
  set "oldName=%%~a"
  set "newName=%oldName:.m4a=%"
  ren %%a "%newName%"
)
```

It returns `The syntax of the command is incorrect.`
I've tried:

```sh
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir  /b /a-d *.m4a.mp3') do (
  set "oldName=%%~a"
  set "newName=%oldName:.m4a=%"
  ren %%a %newName%
)
```

which returns `ft. was unexpected at this time.`
What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: two problems: you need to quote the filenames to process filenames with spaces properly, and [delayed expansion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30282784/variables-are-not-behaving-as-expected/30284028#30284028) to properly use varialbes wihtin the loop: `ren "%%a" "!newname!"`

Comment: @Um9vdAo Open a [command prompt](https://www.howtogeek.com/235101/), run `help` and look on the (incomplete) output list of [Windows Commands](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/windows-commands) with a brief description. Run a command with `/?` to get output the help in language of your Windows like `for /?` and `dir /?` and `set /?` and `ren /?`. You can read also about the commands on already linked Microsoft documentation pages or [SS64.com - A-Z index of Windows CMD commands](https://ss64.com/nt/) which has also __How-to__ guides.

Comment: Wow! Thanks A LOT for the resources and instructions! I really appreciate it. I Will surely look into these! @Mofi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could probably do it like this from [cmd](/questions/tagged/cmd):

```batch-file
For %G In (*.m4a.mp3) Do @For %H In ("%~nG") Do @Ren "%G" "%~nH%~xG"
```

Or like this from a [batch-file](/questions/tagged/batch-file):

```batch-file
@For %%G In (*.m4a.mp3) Do @For %%H In ("%%~nG") Do @Ren "%%G" "%%~nH%%~xG"
```